# What are the benefits of Source Code Integration for a Bug Tracking system?

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking

I'm choosing a Bug/Issue Tracking system for use on our project.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/what-bug-tracking-software-do-you-use) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101774/what-is-your-bug-task-tracking-tool) are helpful in giving systems to evaluate.  However, I have a question raised by looking in to the various products on offer.

Some systems promote Source Code Control System integration as a feature.  This is not something I've used before and looking at the various tools' websites I can't find any detail on precisely what this integration provides.  Is it any more than browsing my repository through the same web interface I use for raising bugs?

So what benefits does such integration offer?  How will it save me time or make our product better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) together with [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/default2.jsp) (a SCM browser) can, when if you commit a changeset with a log messages containing a Jira issue key, such as "PROJ-123", insert a link into the corresponding Jira issue, and Jira will display a link in PROJ-123 to the changeset mentioning that issue.

Jira can also integrate with [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), so that when a build incorporating a fix (i.e. changeset) is performed, the Jira issue mentioned in the log message of that commit will get a comment about the status of the build.

Since an issue tracker is used to keep track of issues with the source code, there are a boatload of features one might imagine in an integrate issue/source-control management system.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server, which not only integrates with the source control, it also integrates with a data warehouse. This allows it to keep track, for instance, of which bugs were caused by which pieces of code, showing which pieces of code need more QA. The forthcoming features in the 2010 version are even more compelling.

Answer (score 1):

The major advantage is that you can raise bugs against specific revisions of source code. This just helps identify the state of the code-base when the bug was noticed. I think a popular product in this space is [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), which integrates with SVN.

Comment: How is that different from selecting the version of the code in combo box in "traditional" system?  Why do I need source code integration?  I want to be sure of any benefits if we're going to down this route.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd say there's one big reason here, and it's that you can work on a **task/issue oriented** way.

I mean:

- every code change you do (everything, from a small quick fix to a big new feature) will be an issue in [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) or [Rally](http://www.rallydev.com/) or Bugzilla, Trac, Mantis, the one you like.
- It means the issue/task tracking system must be easy to use, fast, simple and so on, otherwise developers will hate it
- Then associate every change to the issue, and you're done. You get full traceability (great for diff debugging, you'll miss it if you don't have it), better project tracking, better release management and so on.

You can link each changeset/commit (depending on your scm jargon) to a task, or, if your scm can do it, create a branch for each bugfix, which is even better.

Basically what you get is simple: every change will be documented, or at least linked to the right issue/task.

If you use branches, you can promote things like: always working on stable baselines, reducing mainline corruption (or making it pristine, if you prefer), deciding which tasks integrate and which ones hold until the next release, individually run tests on changes before merging, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[Github](https://github.com) is basically the other way around: so not so much a bug/issue tracking system with included source code version control, but rather source code version control with some bug/issue tracking inserted. I cannot believe no one mentioned it here, because it's way more common this way the other way around these days.

But it's very powerful, you can basically reference everything git offers also in issues: commits, branches, pull-requests. Github even has some "automagic" installed, merging a PR with content like "fixes issue #23", will automatically close issue #23.

Github is also very handy, because most of the open source software one is using nowadays is also hosted there, and you can reference all those libraries in your own issues/pull requests, etc. as well. 
Also most of the typical modern commercial infrastructure around software development will also integrate with Github: [Travis](https://travis-ci.org) or [Codeship](https://codeship.com) will tell you how your builds are doing and even deploy them automatically, [Hound](https://houndci.com) or [Rubocop](http://batsov.com/rubocop/) will tell you how your code looks and [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com) or [Trackduck](https://www.trackduck.com) will push bug reports into your Github issues if you don't want to use their software.

Trac which was mentioned in the answers here feels *really* old if you compare it to Github.